# How to redirect in vue-authenticate npm after successfully login?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, linkedin-api, vue-router, vue-authenticate

I wanted to redirect my application to its original page, after successfully login from vue application. Below is code snippet:

```
Vue.use(VueAuthenticate, {
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',

  providers: {
    linkedin: {
      clientId: 'abc',
      clientSecret:'def',
      name: 'linkedin',
      redirectUri: 'abc.com/linkedin-success',
      requiredUrlParams: ['scope','code','redirectUri','clientId'],
      scope: ['r_emailaddress', 'r_liteprofile'],
      scopeDelimiter: ',',
      oauthType: '2.0',
      popupOptions: { width: 527, height: 582 },
      authRedirect: {path: '/linkedin-success'},
    },[enter image description here][1]
  }

})
```

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQaIQ.png)